# Read List<> object and map to new List<Summary> Object using Enumerable.GroupBy

Tags: c#, list

I have the following input list :

```
    **AccountModel.cs**
    CompanyCode
    BusinessCode
    State
```

I need to iterate thru the List<**AccountModel**> and create the following output List<**SummaryModel**>

```
    **SummaryModel.cs**
       RecordCount
       CompanyCode
       BusinessCode
       State
```

Example input list:

```
   { 
    CompanyCode  = "A",
    BusinessCode = "AAA",
    StateCode    = "GA",
   },

   { 
    CompanyCode  = "A",
    BusinessCode = "AAA",
    StateCode    = "GA",
   },
   { 
    CompanyCode  = "A",
    BusinessCode = "AAA",
    StateCode    = "TN",
   },
   { 
    CompanyCode  = "A",
    BusinessCode = "AAA",
    StateCode    = "TN",
   },
```

Expected Results:

```
    RecordCount  = 2
    CompanyCode  = A
    BusinessCode = AAA
    StateCode    = GA

    RecordCount  = 2
    CompanyCode  = A
    BusinessCode = AAA
    StateCode    = TN
```

So far I am attempting to solve this by using the following:

```
     IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> query = accountModels.GroupBy(accountModel=> accountModel.CompanyCodeModel, accountModel => accountModel.CompanyCodeModel);

        // Iterate over each IGrouping in the collection.
        foreach (IGrouping<string, string> companyCodeGroup in query)
        {
            SummaryModel.CompanyCode = companyCodeGroup.Key;

            foreach (var code in companyCodeGroup)
            {
                SummaryModel.RecordCount++;
            }

    // Print the record count of the IGrouping.
        Console.WriteLine("RecordCount = " + SummaryModel.RecordCount);
        Console.WriteLine("CompanyCode = " + SummaryModel.CompanyCode);
        Console.WriteLine("BusinessCode = " + SummaryModel.BusinessCode);
        Console.WriteLine("StateCode = " + SummaryModel.StateCode);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Actual Results:

```
    RecordCount  = 4
    CompanyCode  = A
    BusinessCode = 
    StateCode    =
```

I have only coded the grouping for company at this time so I realize I'm not printing anything out for BusinessCode and StateCode in this example.

This may be obvious to some but how can I get my expected results for this ?

Comment: `meList.GroupBy(e => new AccountModel{ CompanyCode = e.CompanyCode, BusinessCode = e.BusinessCode, StateCode = e.StateCode }, e => meList.Count(en => en == e));` should return `AccountModel` with occurences count but it's not verified :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `GroupBy` all the fields you want to summarise, i.e. `CompanyCode`, `BusinessCode`, `StateCode`.
You can do this using an anonymous object in the `GroupBy`.

Then calling `Count()` on each grouping will give you the record count. You can use all this to create a `SummaryModel` for each combination.

```
List<SummaryModel> summaryModels = accountModels.GroupBy(accountModel => new {
    accountModel.CompanyCode
    accountModel.BusinessCode
    accountModel.StateCode
}).Select(amSummary => new SummaryModel {
    CompanyCode = amSummary.Key.CompanyCode,
    BusinessCode = amSummary.Key.BusinessCode,
    StateCode = amSummary.Key.StateCode,
    RecordCount = amSummary.Count() 
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be okay.

```
accountModels.Distinct().Select(a => new SummaryModel {
    CompanyCode = a.CompanyCode,
    BusinessCode = a.BusinessCode,
    StateCode = a.StateCode,
    RecordCount = accountModels.Where(
        m => m.CompanyCode == a.CompanyCode && m.BusinessCode = a.BusinessCode && m.StateCode = a.StateCode
    ).Count()
});
```

Comment: I would not reinvent the wheel doing a manual grouping if there is already the .GroupBy function *and* the question is already trying to use it. Not downvoting but will upvote @Rhumborl

Comment: It's not grouping. Grouping groups elements together and this one is counting.

Comment: Yeah, your code does not group, but the question is trying to group and looks like he wants to get a summary using a manual count on the IGrouping. I wonder if your answer, in case there was a database behind, would be performance wise. Would it translate to subqueries? The other aswer definitively would no translate to subqueries.

Comment: To be honest. This method is not performance wise even if there's no database behind. But being honest if someone cares that much about performance C# is not the best shot either.

Comment: Write a wrong linq to sql, entity framework or other ORM query to a database with 100k+ records and it would not matter what language it is written in. I have reduced 14 hour running process to 12 minutes only fixing the queries used to load the data. There were explicits subqueries in 'pretty large tables. BTW, the culprit in that occasion was PL/SQL, not C#. :-)